# \nameref use the long title instead of the short title

Tags: titles, nameref

For my table of contents I need the short title, often formatted with `\newline` so it looks nice. For `\nameref{label}` I need the long title instead of the short title. Is it possible to have `\nameref` use the long title instead of the short title?  Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontotoc]{report}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[Title \newline displayed in toc]{Title displayed in header}\label{test}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \nameref{test}

\end{document}
```

[image: The Title as wanted in the TOC]

[image: The Title as wanted on the Header but not in the body - body uses short title]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`headings=totoc` is a KOMA-Script option. Maybe you can use a **KOMA-Script class**:

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontotoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[tocentry={Title \newline displayed in toc}]{Title displayed in header}\label{test}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \nameref{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you have to use `tocentry={...}` in the optional argument if the short version should not be used for the reference even if option `headings=totoc` is set.

If you load package `hyperref` (instead only `nameref`) then the reference to the chapter title becomes a link.

---

**Update** for **standard class**

Suggestion for a **standard class** with package `hyperref` (or only `nameref`):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}% loads also nameref
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{% to avoid the hyperref warning for \newline
    \def\newline{\relax}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\referencetitle[1]{\def\@currentlabelname{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter[Title \newline displayed in toc]{Title displayed in header}
\referencetitle{Title displayed in header}\label{chap:test}
Some text

\clearpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\nameref{chap:test}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Original answer** for **standard class**

With a **standard class** you can load package `zref`:

```
\documentclass{report}% <- unused (unknown) option removed
\usepackage[user,titleref]{zref}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[Title \newline displayed in toc]{Title displayed in header}
\ztitlerefsetup{title=Title displayed in header}\zlabel{chap:test}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \ztitleref{chap:test}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Additional update for standard class with `zref` and `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[user,titleref]{zref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{% to avoid the hyperref warning for \newline
    \def\newline{\relax}%
}

\newcommand\chapterlabel[1]{\zlabel{#1}\label{#1}}
\newcommand\chapterref[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\ztitleref{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter[Title \newline displayed in toc]{Title displayed in header}
\ztitlerefsetup{title=Title displayed in header}\chapterlabel{chap:test}
Some text

\clearpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \chapterref{chap:test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is my dissertation and the only document class that can be used is report.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Is there an easy way to ad hyperref to add hyperref to the chapter names?

Comment: See my updated answer.